# Derivation of bias-variance decomposition of error

Tags: machine-learning, mathematical-statistics, bias-variance-tradeoff

I am repeating the derivation from slide #12 of http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~wcohen/10-601/bias-variance.pdf

$$E_{D,e}[(f - \hat{y})^2] = E_{D,e}[((f - h) + (h - \hat{y}))^2]$$
$$E[(f - h) ^ 2 + (h - \hat{y}) ^ 2] - 2 (E(fh) - E (f\hat{y}) - E(h^2) + E(h\hat{y}))$$

Basically the following term is claimed to be equal to 0 and **I don't understand how it is 0**:
$$2 (E(fh) - E (f\hat{y}) - E(h^2) + E(h\hat{y}))$$

**Points of confusion:**

1. It seems to claim that
   $$E(f\hat{y}) = E(h\hat{y})$$ and thus the two terms are cancelled out. If so, how are they equal? One has actual function f, while the other has the model function 'h'.
2. Similarly how do other terms cancel out?

Please provide both mathematical proof as well as intuitive understanding as I have wasted hours trying to understand this on my own.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First up, $h$ is not arbitrary, it is defined on the same slide as

$$h=E[h_D(x)]=E[\hat{y}]$$

Note that since it's an expectation, it is a *number*, not a *function*.

---

Next, you have picked the wrong pairs to cancel out. The claim is a bit different:

$$E[fh] = E[f\hat{y}]$$ and $$E[h\hat{y}] = E[h^2]$$

This follows directly from the definition of $h$. E.g.,

$$E[fh] = E[f \cdot E[\hat{y}]] = E[f\hat{y}]$$

... which uses the fact that $f$ is deterministic and $E[E[z]] = E[z]$. The second identity is proven likewise:

$$E[h\hat{y}] = E[E[\hat{y}] \cdot \hat{y}] = E[E[\hat{y}] \cdot E[\hat{y}]] = E[h^2]$$

In summary, the trick works for the specifically chosen $h$. In general, of course, it won't hold.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. If possible, could you also provide an intuitive explanation and/or derivation for E[f. E[y^hat]] = E[f y^hat]? I don't quite see why expectation of (f * expected value of predictions) would necessarily be equal to the expected value of (f * predictions) unless f can be taken outside the E[].